# C++ how to flush std:stringbuf?

Tags: c++, multithreading, streambuf

I need to put the standard output of a process (binary data) to a string buffer and consume it in another thread.

Here is the producer:

```
while (ReadFile(ffmpeg_OUT_Rd, cbBuffer, sizeof(cbBuffer), &byteRead, NULL)){
    tByte += byteRead;   //total bytes
    sb->sputn(cbBuffer, byteRead);
}
m_bIsFinished = true;
printf("%d bytes are generated.\n", tByte);
```

Here is the consumer:

```
while (!PCS_DISPATCHER_INSTANCE->IsFinished())
    Sleep(200);
Sleep(5000);
Mystringbuf* sb = PCS_DISPATCHER_INSTANCE->sb;
printf("Avail: %d\n", sb->in_avail());
```

It turns out that the consumer cannot get all the bytes of the produced by the producer.
( `tByte <> sb->in_avail()` )

Is it a kind of internal buffering problem? If yes, how to force the stringbuf to flush its internal buffer?

Comment: Is m_bIsFinished an `atomic<bool>` or `atomic<int>` ?

Comment: Sleep is not a synchronization primitive. You need one.

Comment: @Christophe Nope, just a primitive boolean

Comment: I tried to print out the in_avail and number of bytes read from the pipe in the same like this `printf("%d, %d\n", tByte, sb->in_avail());` they give the same value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [`streambuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/)has nothing like flush:  writes are done directly into the buffer.  There is a [`pubsync()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/pubsync/) member that could help, if you would use an object derived such as a filebuf.  But this does not apply to your case.

Your issue certainly comes from a a **data race** on [`sputn()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/sputn/) or `is_avail()`. Either protect access to the streambuf via a mutex, or via an [`atomic`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/). If `m_bIsFinished` is not an atomic, and depending on your implementation of `isFinished()`, the synchronisation between the threads might not be guaranteed (*for example: producer could write to memory, but consumer still obtains an outdated value from the CPU memory cache*), which could conduct to such a data race.

**Edit:**

If you'd experience the issue within a single thread, thus eliminating any potential racing condition, it may come from implementation of `streambuf`.  I could experience this with MSVC13 in a single thread application:

- tracing showed that number of bytes read were accurate, but `in_avail()` result was always smaller or equal to tByte through the whole loop.
- when reading the streambuf, the correct total number of bytes were read (thus more than indicated by in_avail()).

This behaviour is compliant.  According to C++ standard: *`in_avail()` shall return egptr() - gptr() **if a read position is available**, and otherwhise showmanyc().*  The latter is defined as *returning an **estimate** of the number of characters available in the sequence.*  The only guarantee given is that you could read at least `in_avail()` bytes without encountering eof.

Workaround use `sb->pubseekoff(0,ios::end)- sb->pubseekoff(0,ios::beg);` to count the number of bytes available, and make sure you're repositioned at sb->pubseekoff(0,ios::beg) beofre you read your streambuf.

Comment: Yeh but I have sleep the consumer thread for 5 seconds, so i guess there are some other problems?

Comment: Great! that works. I thought in_avail() would work like as its name described.